# Vuejs / laravel image upload receiving empty array

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have looked at a lot of Q&A on stackoverflow but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I am building a webshop (to improve my coding), currently working on Add Product bit.

The idea is that I can add a product, which can have multiple 'products'. For example, a T-shirt is one product, but the same t-shirt can be red/green color small/medium size and those have their own stock.

**HTML in Vue component**

```
<label class="btn-bs-file btn  btn-primary">
    Add picture
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" @change="onFileChange($event, index)"/>
</label>
<div v-for="image in form.products[index].files" :key="image.id">
    <img :src="image.preview" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
onFileChange(e, index) {
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!files.length)
        return;
    this.createImage(files[0], index);
},
createImage(file, index) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var vm = this

    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', file)

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        vm.form.products[index].files.push({
            file: formData,
            preview: e.target.result
            });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},

submit: function() {
    let vm = this
    this.$api.post('products', this.form, 
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            // vm.upload(res.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.message('error', error, 'Error')
            console.log(error)
        })
},
```

**PHP**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

This is structure (and the response). As you can see, the file is an empty array and I want the actual file here.

```
{
  "name": "Random Name",
  "brand": null,
  "description": null",
  "categories": [],
  "note": null,
  "products": [
    {
      "attributes": [],
      "color": "random",
      "state": "active",
      "price": "12",
      "files": [
        {
          "file": [],
          "preview": "data:image/png;base64,"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I look in my browser (vuejs plugin) it shows me this:

[image]

So I guess the formData is in there, but I'm not sure if this is a correct way of doing this and how I would get the formData in the backend.

(I've been at this for over 10 hours, I tried a lot of different things in both backend and frontend, too much to list here..)

Comment: Have a look at Laravel's file upload documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: I know how to get the file. But the formData is not coming through.